# ValueError: Shape of passed values is (12, 8), indices imply (12, 12) and .describe()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, size, shapes

LC is a list of 12 candidate names, Smpc is a list of dataframes per candidate with their votes in each voting station but with other information, and Smpcd is a list of dataframes description per candidate but only describing their amount of votes per votiong station.

```
    F = [] 
    for i in range(len(LC)):
        Smpc.append(Smp[Smp['NUMDEPCAND'].isin(LC[i])])
        Smpcd.append( Smpc[i]["SUM(V.NBRVOIX)"].describe())                 
        F.append(Smpcd[i].tolist())
    HELP  = pd.DataFrame( np.array(F) , columns=LC )
    print(HELP)
```

I think i would want the indices to imply (12, 8)

Comment: Can you provide a small, *independent* code example that reproduces the issue you have? So far, I do not even understand what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

The programme wanted me to inverse the list

```
for i in range(len(F[i])):
            F3=[]
            for j in range(len(F)):
                F3.append(F[j][i])
            F2.append(F3)
```